# UITableView refusing to go to detailViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, uitableview, segue

*Edit: This question has been moved to [Getting an error from Xcode that is not on the internet related to index path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212906/getting-an-error-from-xcode-that-is-not-on-the-internet-related-to-index-path) because this question was fixed but presented with a new error.*

I have been at this for 4 days! I am getting no errors in the log, yet whenever I click on my cell that is populated with a dynamic array downloaded from mysql, it does not transition. Interestingly, I got no response from the self placed nslogs in prepareForSegue...

ViewController.h

```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,
 CLLocationManagerDelegate,NSXMLParserDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
     IBOutlet UILabel *Label;


    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

    NSMutableArray *coolarray;

    float latitude;
    float longitude;
}



@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;


@end
```

I've excluded the xml downloaded data that was parsed, but left the values for the nsarray below in my implementation file

```
   #import "ViewController.h"
    #import "DetailViewController.h"
    #import "Player.h"

    @interface ViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation ViewController



    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    - (void)dealloc
    {
        [super dealloc];
        [self.locationManager release];
        if ( coolarray )
            [coolarray release];
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        coolarray = NULL;

        self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

    - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        return YES;
    }

    // Table data delegate
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        if ( coolarray != NULL ) {
            return [coolarray count];
        }
        return 0;
    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            Player *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Player"];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[Player alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Player"] autorelease];
        }


        NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        UILabel *nameLabel =[cell textLabel];
        [nameLabel setText:[itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"name"]];
        return cell;
    }
                - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
                        Player *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Player"];

                    if (cell == nil)
                    {
                        cell = [[[Player alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Player"] autorelease];
                    }


                    NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    UILabel *nameLabel =[cell textLabel];
                    [nameLabel setText:[itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"name"]];
                    return cell;
                }

        -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            NSString *selectedLang = [coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


            DetailViewController *myDetViewCont = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 

            myDetViewCont.myDogLang = selectedLang; 
            [self  performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDogDetail" sender:nil];

            [myDetViewCont release]; 
            myDetViewCont = nil;

        }

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{ 
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDogDetail"])
    {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView
                                    indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *dogLang = [self.coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        detailViewController.myDogLang = dogLang;
                    }

            }
@end
```

DetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
 {

    IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

    NSString *myDogLang;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myDogLang;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize myLabel;
@synthesize myDogLang;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myLabel.text = myDogLang;
        self.myLabel.text = [self.myLabel objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myLabel release];
    [myDogLang release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

I've also added a picture to show my connection:
[image]

Comment: Does this work "myLabel = [[NSArray alloc] .." myLabel seems to be UILabel and you are assigning to NSArray. Can you check it.

Comment: Do you implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?  How is the segue supposed to be invoked?

Comment: Sorry. Accidentally left that part out in my question. I've updated the question with didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Do you actually have a segue in your storyboard with that identifier? It looks like you are using NIBs.

Comment: Yeah. I do. I'm using storyboard and I have a storyboard transition  "showDogDetail". What should I call instead of initWithNibName to reflect the storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing and matching a few different styles here... I suggest simplifying your code:

1)  Delete the current segue between the table and detail view.  Create a new one by holding the control key and dragging from the prototype cell (I'm assuming this is a prototype table) to the destination view. Don't forget to name the identifier the same name you are using in your prepareForSegue code).  Also, if you have the table view controller embedded in a Navigation controller (which is what is typically expected on a navigable table view), the style of the segue should be 'Push.'   Otherwise the style should be 'Modal' (though, depending on the usability of your app, you may want to reconsider this approach).

[image]

2)  What's going on with the Player class?  Is this a class that extends UITableViewCell?  When you click on the prototype cell in the storyboard, what class is listed in the identity inspector?  Is it Player or UITableViewCell?  What is the identifier of the cell in the attribute inspector?  Is it Player or blank (given your code, it needs to be "Player")? Try taking the Player class, at least temporarily, out of the picture.  Keep the identifier of the cell as `Player`, but in the identity inspector, set the custom class of the prototype cell to `UITableViewCell`. Change your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Player"];

    NSDictionary *itemAtIndex = (NSDictionary *)[self.coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;
}
```

Also as a side note here, you're indicating in this method that the members of coolarray are an NSDictionary type.  In prepareForSegue you are treating the members of coolarray as NSStrings.  They can't be both.

3)  Get rid of the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.  This is important.  You have two competing methods of segues happening here. One that is set up in the Storyboard and this method.  The way your code is written right now, a click on the cell will call prepareForSegue -> didSelect -> prepareForSegue.  Everything that you are attempting to do in here can be done in the `prepareForSegue:` method (see the next step).

4)  Change your prepareForSegue: method to look something like this (you could even get rid of the "if" statement since you only have one segue right now):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{ 
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDogDetail"])
    {
        DetailViewController *detailViewController =
        [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView
                                    indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *dogLang = [self.coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // or if the array contains NSDictionaries, change the previous line to:
        // NSString *dogLang = [[self.coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
        detailViewController.myDogLang = dogLang;
    }
}
```

5)  Your DetailViewController's viewDidLoad method is overriding the label text with some bad code (a UILabel is not an array).  Change the code to:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myLabel.text = self.myDogLang;
}
```

Given some of the conceptual issues I've mentioned above, I highly recommend reading [Apple's Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).  It'll help clarify the life cycle and flow for you.

Comment: I put an nslog like you said and I am getting no response from either. I updated my code with the spots that I placed them.

Comment: Ah. I'm getting the error (use of undeclared identifier indexpath. Do you have any suggestions on how I go about doing that?

Comment: Change where it says `myIndexPath` to just `indexPath` (I've updated the code above).

Comment: Well, I'm still not getting any response from the logs and the transition is not working. Thanks though. I'm going to upload the header file and more of the implementation just in case I am missing a step somewhere.

Comment: Make sure you put the @ symbol before the string in your NSLog statement.  You forgot that in the code you posted: NSLog(@"test");

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I had them in my project.

Comment: I've added a picture of my connection and updated my code to reflect almost everything (excluding the actual data retrieval view mysql and xml). You can also get a good idea of what I am trying to do here.

Comment: @user1776234 Added some comments to my answer.

Comment: So, I have made a lot of adjustments. I can get it to move on user click now. But when I want it to display the array, it crashes with an error not on the internet. Here is the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212906/getting-an-error-from-xcode-that-is-not-on-the-internet-related-to-index-path. I have given you credit because your answers have helped fix this question.

Answer (score 0):

1- you should choose which approach you want to use: segue with connection inside the storyboard or a programmatically loaded detail controller (using didSelectRowAtIndexPath). Now you are doing both things: no good. Try to comment all your didSelectRowAtIndexPath code and use only storyboard.
Moreover, in your didSelectRowAtIndexPath you are loading detail vc from a nib??? Which nib? You don't have nibs, you have a storyboard! (You can programmatically load things from storyboard, but the code is different)

2- if you use Push for the segue, you MUST HAVE an UINavigationController in your storyboard. Put the nav controller, when you place it in the storyboard it comes with a UITableViewController attached. Remove this UITV and attach yours. 
Reconnect the cell to the detail controller and remember to give an identifier name to the connection, be sure that the connection starts from the cell.
I'm not sure if you need UINavigationController even for the modal segue.

Try and let me know

Comment: Ok, I have done all of #2. For #1, if I can transfer my array coolarray visually in storyboard, I would prefer it that way. However, I am willing to do it programmatically in storyboard. The problem is, I have never done this with dynamic cells before, so I would be very thankful for any links or examples! I have searched the internet, but nothing seems to work properly for my case...

Comment: @user1776234 Your code needs a LOT more fixing than just switching to a UINavigationController. Please read what I wrote above carefully...

Comment: So, I have made a lot of adjustments. I can get it to move on user click now. But when I want it to display the array, it crashes with an error not on the internet. Here is the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13212906/getting-an-error-from-xcode-that-is-not-on-the-internet-related-to-index-path