# Getting an error from Xcode that is not on the internet related to index path

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have searched the internet and got absolutely no results for this. My ios app is just a simple navigation controller with a indexpath that should send the title of the row selected of a custom dynamic cell () to a uilabel. The catch is that the datasource is from mysql that is xml parsed in an nsarray (called coolarray). The error happens just before moving to the next view and is in the log as: **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '[__NSDictionaryI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8887670'.** However, it does give the nslog result of indexPathrow:0 or 1 or whatever was selected. It must be a problem with the delivery of the array to the uilabel, but I cannot figure it out! I have left out the code for the custom cell, because that isn't likely the reason for the error and works fine (plus is dead simple). This is a followup to an earlier question of mine at [UITableView refusing to go to detailViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13206030/uitableview-refusing-to-go-to-detailviewcontroller/13209379#13209379), but that code is no longer relevant because, as you can see below, my code has greatly changed.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "Player.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,
 CLLocationManagerDelegate,NSXMLParserDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;

    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

    NSMutableArray *coolarray;

    float latitude;
    float longitude;
}
@property(nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView * tableView; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "LoadingViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [self.locationManager release];
    if ( coolarray )
        [coolarray release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    coolarray = NULL;

    self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

// Table data delegate
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ( coolarray != NULL ) {
        return [coolarray count];
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        Player *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Player"];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[Player alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Player"] autorelease];
    }
     NSDictionary *itemAtIndex =(NSDictionary *)[coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [itemAtIndex objectForKey:@"name"];
    return cell;
}




// XML request and parsing
- (void)updateLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation {
    if ( coolarray ) {
        [coolarray release];
    }
    coolarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    if ( newLocation ) {
        latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    }

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(censored)"];

    NSXMLParser *locationParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
    [locationParser setDelegate:self];
    [locationParser parse];


    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"location"]) {
        [coolarray addObject:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:attributeDict]];
    }
}

// GPS handling
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    [self updateLocation:newLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

// Search bar handling
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)sb {
    [self updateLocation:NULL];
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)sb
{
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {


}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier  isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
{
    NSIndexPath * indexPath=[self->_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    LoadingViewController* destViewController= segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.myProgLang=[coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"indexPathrow:%d",indexPath.row);
}
}

@end
```

LoadingViewController.h (my detail view)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoadingViewController : UIViewController
 {


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *myProgLang;

@end
```

LoadingViewController.m (my detail view)

```
#import "LoadingViewController.h"

@interface LoadingViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoadingViewController
@synthesize myLabel, myProgLang;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myLabel.text = myProgLang;
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [myLabel release];
    [myProgLang release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your array appears to be a collection of dictionary objects.  When you are about to segue you are taking a dictionary out of the object and are trying to store it as an NSString property.

Try changing your prepareForSegue: method as follows:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier  isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        NSIndexPath * indexPath=[self->_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        LoadingViewController* destViewController= segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.myProgLang=[[coolarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSLog(@"indexPathrow:%d",indexPath.row);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks again! This is #4 that you've solved for me. I really can't thank you enough!